# How do I perform this cross-validation for ridge/lasso regression using randomly generated data?

Tags: r, lasso-regression

Here is my code:

```
library(leaps)
library(glmnet)


set.seed(7)
x <- runif(100,0,1)
y <- 1 + 2*x^2 + 4*x^3 + x^4 + rnorm(100,0,1)
data_1<- data.frame(x,y)

xridge<- model.matrix(y~x+I(x^2)+I(x^3)+I(x^4)+I(x^5)+I(x^6)+I(x^7)+I(x^8)+I(x^9)+I(x^10), data = data_1)

yridge<-data_1$y


crossval<-cv.glmnet(xridge, yridge, alpha=0)
```

I keep getting error `Error in glmnet(x, y, weights = weights, offset = offset, lambda = lambda, : number of observations in y (0) not equal to the number of rows of x (100)`
I know that `matrix.matrix` removes all NA values, so my `Y` variable only has NA values it seems. But how would I go about doing this problem then? I can understand how to do it with data with actual columns and a certain predictor, but this data is random with a Y predictor.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define data_1$y? –
I edited your code to fix what I suspect was a simple oversight.

```
data_1<- data.frame(x,y)
> 
> xridge<- model.matrix(y~x+I(x^2)+I(x^3)+I(x^4)+I(x^5)+I(x^6)+I(x^7)+I(x^8)+I(x^9)+I(x^10), data = data_1)
> 
> yridge<-data_1$y
> 
> 
> crossval<-cv.glmnet(xridge, yridge, alpha=0)
> str(crossval)
List of 12
 $ lambda    : num [1:100] 2000 1822 1661 1513 1379 ...
 $ cvm       : num [1:100] 4.88 4.82 4.8 4.79 4.78 ...
 $ cvsd      : num [1:100] 0.676 0.673 0.662 0.661 0.66 ...
 $ cvup      : num [1:100] 5.56 5.49 5.46 5.45 5.44 ...
 $ cvlo      : num [1:100] 4.21 4.15 4.13 4.13 4.12 ...
 $ nzero     : Named int [1:100] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:100] "s0" "s1" "s2" "s3" ...
 $ call      : language cv.glmnet(x = xridge, y = yridge, alpha = 0)
 $ name      : Named chr "Mean-Squared Error"
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mse"
 $ glmnet.fit:List of 12
  ..$ a0       : Named num [1:100] 3.02 3 3 3 2.99 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:100] "s0" "s1" "s2" "s3" ...
  ..$ beta     :Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  .. .. ..@ i       : int [1:1000] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  .. .. ..@ p       : int [1:101] 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 ...
  .. .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 11 100
  .. .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:11] "(Intercept)" "x" "I(x^2)" "I(x^3)" ...
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:100] "s0" "s1" "s2" "s3" ...
  .. .. ..@ x       : num [1:1000] 6.67e-36 6.64e-36 6.89e-36 7.12e-36 7.28e-36 ...
  .. .. ..@ factors : list()
  ..$ df       : int [1:100] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
  ..$ dim      : int [1:2] 11 100
  ..$ lambda   : num [1:100] 2000 1822 1661 1513 1379 ...
  ..$ dev.ratio: num [1:100] 1.47e-35 1.72e-02 1.88e-02 2.06e-02 2.26e-02 ...
  ..$ nulldev  : num 478
  ..$ npasses  : int 551
  ..$ jerr     : int 0
  ..$ offset   : logi FALSE
  ..$ call     : language glmnet(x = xridge, y = yridge, alpha = 0)
  ..$ nobs     : int 100
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "elnet" "glmnet"
 $ lambda.min: num 0.2
 $ lambda.1se: num 1.41
 $ index     : int [1:2, 1] 100 79
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "1se"
  .. ..$ : chr "Lambda"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "cv.glmnet"
```

I was not sure if poly(x,10) in the formula would succeed but if it doesn’t throw an error it would be preferable from a statistical validity standpoint. –

```
xridge<- model.matrix(y~poly(x,10), data = data_1)
> 
> yridge<-data_1$y
> crossval2<-cv.glmnet(xridge, yridge, alpha=0)
> str(crossval2)
List of 12
 $ lambda    : num [1:100] 1864 1699 1548 1410 1285 ...
 $ cvm       : num [1:100] 4.89 4.88 4.88 4.88 4.88 ...
 $ cvsd      : num [1:100] 0.675 0.675 0.674 0.674 0.674 ...
 $ cvup      : num [1:100] 5.56 5.56 5.55 5.55 5.55 ...
 $ cvlo      : num [1:100] 4.21 4.21 4.21 4.2 4.2 ...
 $ nzero     : Named int [1:100] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:100] "s0" "s1" "s2" "s3" ...
 $ call      : language cv.glmnet(x = xridge, y = yridge, alpha = 0)
 $ name      : Named chr "Mean-Squared Error"
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mse"
 $ glmnet.fit:List of 12
  ..$ a0       : Named num [1:100] 3.02 3.02 3.02 3.02 3.02 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:100] "s0" "s1" "s2" "s3" ...
  ..$ beta     :Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  .. .. ..@ i       : int [1:1000] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  .. .. ..@ p       : int [1:101] 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 ...
  .. .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 11 100
  .. .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:11] "(Intercept)" "poly(x, 10)1" "poly(x, 10)2" "poly(x, 10)3" ...
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:100] "s0" "s1" "s2" "s3" ...
  .. .. ..@ x       : num [1:1000] 1.88e-35 7.45e-36 -2.79e-38 -4.16e-37 6.62e-37 ...
  .. .. ..@ factors : list()
  ..$ df       : int [1:100] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
  ..$ dim      : int [1:2] 11 100
  ..$ lambda   : num [1:100] 1864 1699 1548 1410 1285 ...
  ..$ dev.ratio: num [1:100] 1.72e-36 2.18e-03 2.39e-03 2.63e-03 2.88e-03 ...
  ..$ nulldev  : num 478
  ..$ npasses  : int 286
  ..$ jerr     : int 0
  ..$ offset   : logi FALSE
  ..$ call     : language glmnet(x = xridge, y = yridge, alpha = 0)
  ..$ nobs     : int 100
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "elnet" "glmnet"
 $ lambda.min: num 0.186
 $ lambda.1se: num 0.431
 $ index     : int [1:2, 1] 100 91
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "1se"
  .. ..$ : chr "Lambda"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "cv.glmnet"
```

I checked, and `poly(x,10)` succeeds and definitely would be preferable. Building polynomials with `I(x^n)` creates correlated data where none was present. The large residuals from the high powers dominates the statistical machinery. The `poly` function creates orthogonal polynomials which are less susceptible to this sort of error.